# ‘bring together/ bond together’

Tags: word-usage

everyone, I’m very glad to join here today.

> There is, however, something special about puppet shows in Turkey. In the popular puppet theater in Turkey, the puppets are not clearly visible. Rather, they are shadowy. . . . The traditional puppet theater strengthens the cultural identity of the Turkish people and ***brings*** them closer together through entertainment.

*source; our local textbook for high school students

Can the “***brings***“ above be replaced with ”***bonds***“ in that context? I wonder if two verbs could be used interchangeably to indicate the emotional joining together.

Comment: ***Bonds*** is perfectly valid, but extremely uncommon for the exact context. See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brings+people+closer+together%2Cbonds+people+closer+together%2Cbinds+people+closer+together&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), showing that it's nearly always ***brings***. And on the relatively uncommon occasions where it's *not*, we're far more likely to use ***binds*** than ***bonds***. Note that both ***bonds*** and ***binds*** are far more emphatic "figurative" usages - ***brings*** is really just about literal proximity

Answer (score 1):

No, "**bonds**" does not mean the same as "**brings**", but it does mean roughly the same as "**brings them closer (together)**", so this is the replacement I would make:

> The traditional puppet theater strengthens the cultural identity of the Turkish people and **bonds them (together)** through entertainment.

The word "together" can remain as an optional intensifier.